# multi use of one js function in one HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the following JavaScript function with the given HTML code to the ID names NTag, VTag, TTag, TATag, and VATag. I have bound the function with NTag. Please tell me how can I use this code to generate HEX for all the values presented in the respective inputs.
The function is creating HEX code for Decimals. It is working well with the one to which I have bonded it.

JS Function:

```
function fun1() {
    number = document.getElementById("NTag").value;
    h = parseInt(number, 10).toString(16);
    if (h.length<=1){
        h = "0"+h;
    }else{
        h = h;
    }
    document.getElementById("NTagHex").textContent = h;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QR Code Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css"
</head>
<body onload="fun1()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Tag</th>
            <th>Length</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="number" id="NTag" name="NTag" value="1"></th>
            <th><input type="number" onchange="fun2()" id="NLength" name="NLength"></th>
            <th><input type="text" onchange="fun3(); concatenate();" id="NValue" name="NValue"></th>
            <th><p>Company Name</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><p id="NTagHex"></p></th>
            <th><p id="NLengthHex"></p></th>
            <th><p id="NValueHex"></p></th>
            <th><p id="Hex1"></p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="number" id="VTag" name="VTag" value="2"></th>
            <th><input type="number" id="VLength" name="VLength"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="VValue" name="VValue"></th>
            <th><p>Company VAT</p></th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="number" id="TTag" name="TTag" value="3"></th>
            <th><input type="number" id="TLength" name="TLength"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="TValue" name="TValue"></th>
            <th><p>Date & Time of Invoice Creation</p></th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="number" id="TATag" name="TATag" value="4"></th>
            <th><input type="number" id="TALength" name="TALength"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="TAValue" name="TAValue"></th>
            <th><p>Total Amount with VAT</p></th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="number" id="VATag" name="VATag" value="5"></th>
            <th><input type="number" id="VALength" name="VALength"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="VAValue" name="VAValue"></th>
            <th><p>VAT Amount</p></th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
            <th><p></p></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script src="Script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use a single function for all of them. so instead of fun1() fun2() ... lets use a fun() with this code:

```
function fun(id) {
    number = document.getElementById(id).value;
    h = parseInt(number, 10).toString(16);
    if (h.length <= 1) {
        h = "0" + h;
    } else {
        h = h;
    }
document.getElementById(id + 'some constant. here is: HEX').textContent = h;
}
```

so you can use fun() in ur html like below:

```
<input type="number" onchange="fun('NTag');" id="NTag" name="NTag " value="5 "></th>
...
<p id="NTagHex"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll apply it and will back to you

Comment: I tried to apply it but there are two ids involved in "NTag" and "NTagHex". I also did the following but did not succeed. 'function fun(a,b) {
    number = document.getElementById(a).value;
    h = parseInt(number, 10).toString(16);
    if (h.length <= 1) {
        h = "0" + h;
    } else {
        h = h;
    }
document.getElementById(b).textContent = h;
}' and in html '<input type="number" onchange="fun('NTag', 'NTagHex');" id="NTag" name="NTag " value="5 "></th>
...
<p id="NTagHex"></p>' Please tell me where I am wrong.